# Set git diff to a default value

Tags: git, diff

I previously changed my git diff tool with `git config --global diff.external <diff-tool-name>`. I decided I don't like that tool and wanted to switch back.

I tried meddling around and did something like: `git config --global diff.external git-diff`. Now calling `git diff` to see unstaged changes yields:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument '48e66b706d21398f28240810e7fc0d44d8f92d99': unknown revision or path not in the working tr
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions
external diff died, stopping at somefile.ext.
```

How do I set my `git diff` command to use the default command line git diff that came with git. Something like:

`git config --global diff.`

and then what?

Comment: Can you explain further? `git diff` is the default command line git diff, if you want gui, its `git difftool`.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be thanks! I didn't know this. Finally I can see diffs with `vimdiff` without the need of external scripts or configuration changes :)

Comment: Your global config file is a simple `ini` file which you can edit by hand.

Comment: Needed the same to use git with RStudio.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3713865/2624806) also worked fine.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Try
`git config --global --unset diff`

and

`git config --global --unset diff.external`

See the explanation of [`git config`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) for further details.

Comment: this say error: key does not contain a section: diff. any suggestion!

Comment: Works  like a charm! Thanks mate!

Comment: Well, that's not a solution. What if you configured your global environment and you want to do a local override using GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF?

Comment: I get an error `error: key does not contain a section: diff` when I run the first command.