# Conditional External Tool Git Diff Comparison

Tags: git

I've created a small script to launch `meld` when using `git diff`, [similar to this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955752/set-git-diff-to-a-default-value)

This is fine and all, however due to various drawbacks I'd only like `git diff` to launch meld in certain circumstances.  Is there a way to create an alias in my `.gitconfig` to allow me to launch `meld` under certain circumstances?

Thus enters `git difftool` a way of launching external programs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ends up, yes and no.  To do this, you'll want to use `git difftool`.  There are a few gotchas on the way to getting that to work though.

First off, it'll ask you what editor you want to use **every time**, which is a pain.  You'll want to pass a `-y` flag into `difftool`.

Assuming the default diff tool `git` uses, you'll also want to specify exactly what tool you'll want.  You can do this two ways, one through `-t <toolname>` the other `--tool=<toolname>`.

Assuming you'll always want to default to to be a specific tool, you can set this using the `.gitconfig`.

```
[difftool]
    gui = meld
```

This *should* set the default tool `difftool` asks you, let me know if this part isn't accurate.

Here's a final copy of my `.gitconfig` that has a working alias for `difftoool`.

```
[alias]
    mdiff = difftool -t "meld" -y
```

This has the extra benefit of not having to always wait for meld to open, as well as still being able to get a text diff on the command line.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Could you please try to reformulate the text more clearly and simply? I have exactly the same problem  and I am desperately looking for a solution. I would like to launch meld when I am in `X` and `diff` when in console.

Comment: @MartinVegter It is very clear and simple.  I set up `git difftool` to launch an external diff tool when using the alias `git mdiff <file-to-diff>`.  If you want it to "just work" then copy the alias section into your `.gitconfig`