# Why does "git difftool" not open the tool directly?

Tags: git, diff, difftool

I configured `git` like this:

```
git config --global diff.tool meld
```

When I run:

```
git difftool
```

I get the following message:

```
Viewing: 'hello.txt'
Hit return to launch 'meld':
```

Then, if I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, `meld` will launch.

How can I disable this message, so that `meld` will be launched straight away after typing `git difftool`?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220309/git-difftool-open-all-diff-files-immediately-not-in-serial

Comment: I think also valid question is: why by default additional approval is needed?

Comment: Сonfirmation can be useful when difftool runs a new window for each file (like vscode), then You can decide for each file, should it be opened or not.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

```
man git-difftool

OPTIONS
   -y, --no-prompt
       Do not prompt before launching a diff tool.
```

Answer (score 442):

There's also an option:

```
difftool.prompt
  Prompt before each invocation of the diff tool.
```

The following command turns off the prompt globally (for all repos):

```
git config --global difftool.prompt false
```

Which is like writing in `~/.gitconfig`:
(or in `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\.gitconfig`)

```
[difftool]
  prompt = false
```

Comment: This is a better answer because it will handle the case as the default action, which will allow the question writer to continue using git-difftool as they want.

Comment: Actually the `--add` option is misplaced here. It means to add the setting "prompt=false" to whatever entries of "promt" are there already, whereas the goal is to replace the current value or add it in the first place. This behaviour is achieved without `--add`.

Comment: Make sure you don't put `propmt = false` under [difftool "toolname"]` section by accident. It doesn't work. It should be under `[difftool]` section.

Comment: Don't set `difftool.prompt false` without also setting `diff.tool vimdiff` (or whatever you prefer). Some day you will copy your config to a new system and you are going to get launched into a strange env. Might as well do your future self a favor and take care of everything at once.

Comment: @BrunoBronosky I had set `[merge]` to use tool (and it worked). This uses `[difftool]`. Am I missing any... tool?