# Invoking external difftool from git-gui?

Tags: git, git-gui, difftool

I have p4merge configured so that from the command line if I do a "git difftool ... " then the external diff tool opens up correctly.

I would like to open the external difftool from "git gui" instead of the command line. Is this possible?

Is seems git-gui allows one to add a tool. But it is unclear to me how to get it working. Any pointers?

Answer (score 7):

If you already have `git difftool` set up you can add an item for it:

[image: git-gui Tools->Add dialog difftool setup]

Add Tool dialog transcription:

```
Tool Details box:
    Name: difftool
    Command: git difftool $FILENAME

Show a dialog before running: unchecked
    Ask the user to select a revision (sets $REVISION): unchecked
    Ask the user for additional arguments (sets $ARGS): unchecked

Don't show the command output window: checked
Run only if a diff is selected ($FILENAME not empty): checked
  Add globally: checked
```

Not super-useful though, since there doesn't seem to be a way to assign a hotkey or double-click action to it.

Might need to add a `-y` to the `difftool` command if it's [asking you annoying questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897517/why-does-git-difftool-not-open-the-tool-directly).

Comment: Thanks. And use `git difftool -y $FILENAME` otherwise it gets stuck in a `Run kdiff3 ?` prompt.

Comment: Double-click support for this is here: https://github.com/patraulea/git/pull/1/files (you'll have to patch /usr/lib/git-core/git-gui)

Comment: Sorry for the very late question. To add insult to injury, it's also a pretty dumb question. This doesn't work with Windows does it?

Comment: @KeyvanSadralodabai: Yup, works fine with Beyond Compare 3 on Windows.  Had to use `git difftool -y $FILENAME` to [suppress a startup question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897517/why-does-git-difftool-not-open-the-tool-directly) though.

Comment: @genpfault Yes, I added a bunch of commands to it. The double-click script though, I couldn't make it work as it is for Linux only. I'll update if I find a way to do it for Windows.