# vimdiff between current and previous git version of a file

Tags: git, vim, vimdiff

Is there a way of using vimdiff to compare the current version of a file and the **same** file n git versions ago?

*For example*, I'm working on the file **foo.c** on the branch **master**. I'd like to do a vimdiff between foo.c and foo.c from **master~10**, to copy one or two lines across from the old version.

PS I'm aware of **git cherry pick**, but that's for whole files, not just a couple of lines.

Answer (score 19):

I was adding a PPS about this not being a use case for **git difftool**, then started wondering "*what exactly does git difftool do...*".

Solution is:

```
git difftool master master~10 -- foo.c
```

That is, presuming difftool is already set up correctly in ~/.gitconfig:

```
[diff]
  tool = vimdiff
[difftool]
  prompt = false
```

Answer (score 11):

For working with Git under Vim, the [fugitive.vim - A Git wrapper so awesome, it should be illegal](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2975) plugin is very useful. Check it out!

The vimdiff can be made with `:Gdiff [revision]`.

Answer (score 8):

A solution that works without overriding the git config would be

```
vimdiff file.tex <( git show master~2:file.tex )
```

Answer (score 3):

Possible duplicate of [Viewing all `git diffs` with vimdiff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713765/viewing-all-git-diffs-with-vimdiff)

Comment: Wow Trev, you're quick off the mark. How is it you saw this question so fast, have you got a bot running?!?!