# How to setup coloured git diff with vim as a pager

Tags: git, vim, diff

I am unable to configure git to follow my requests:

1. use vim as a diff pager
2. keep colours for diff when adding files in interactive mode

My `~/.gitconfig` setup:

```
[color]
    ui = auto
    # diff = false

[pager]
    diff = vim -
```

With this configuration the interactive mode for `git add --interactive` produces coloured output as expected:

[image: interactive adding]

The downside of this is that diff in vim is corrupted. See the output of `git diff`:

[image: diff using vim]

When using `git diff | vim -` the colours are OK but I'm too lazy to type the full command. Is there any known method that preserves colours in both cases?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39470081/vim-check-if-running-as-a-pager on how to automatically execute :AnsiEsc upon load.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to install [AnsiEsc plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=302) and run `:AnsiEsc` just after loading file. You can set pager to `vim -c AnsiEsc -` to do this.

Alternatively, use vim own highlighting: using the same method (`-c command`) run

```
%sm/\e.\{-}m//g
set ft=diff
```

:

```
    diff = "vim -c '%sm/\\e.\\{-}m//g' -c 'set ft=diff' -"
```

Comment: perfect, thanks! I used a slightly improved version that sets the cursor at the top of the buffer after substitution. It also ignores empty diffs: _diff = "vim -c '%sm/\\e.\\{-}m//ge' -c 'set ft=diff' -c 'normal gg' -"_

Comment: I added -c 'setlocal buftype=nofile' to prevent vim from complaining about unsaved changes when trying to :q

Answer (score 4):

You have two alternatives here.

**[Use Vimdiff as a difftool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3713865/1076493)**

```
$ git config --global diff.tool vimdiff
$ git config --global difftool.prompt false
$ git config --global alias.d difftool

[diff]
    tool = vimdiff
[difftool]
    prompt = false
[alias]
    d = difftool # Not needed, just a convenience. $ git difftool, still works.
```

**Regular Git diff, but with color highlithing.**

```
$ git config --global color.ui true

[color]
    ui = true
```

Right now, you have a weird mix. You can of course use both, but the `pager` is messing up things.
The reason you get `^[32m` etc is because you're trying to read shell colors in Vim. This doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try these settings:

```
git config --global diff.tool vimdiff
git config --global merge.tool vimdiff

git config --global difftool.prompt false
```