# Is there a neovim version of vimdiff

Tags: neovim

I've started using nvim ([neovim](https://neovim.io)) recently. It generally works well, but when I run vimdiff, I noticed that I got the startup errors I got when I ran regular vim. I've fixed those so that both vim and nvim run without errors on my system, so vimdiff works fine now. But it makes me wonder: is there a neovim version of vimdiff? Or should I just maintain both vim and neovim so that regular vim works fine for vimdiff?

Comment: `vimdiff` is just vim as if the `-d` option is given. It even links to plain vim. Doesn't neovim have -d? And what happens if you symlink vimdiff to neovim?

Comment: I see. So the vim executable conditionally behaves based upon the name of arg[0], and if it is `vimdiff` then behave like -d was passed. If I symlink vimdiff to nvim as you suggest, then it just behaves like nvim with two files passed to it (no diff is done). Making an nvimdiff doesn't work either. I assume it must not have this conditional behavior. I can use `-d` as you suggest. @GavinHaynes, if you post the suggestion of `-d` as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yeah, you can use the `-d` option to open nvim in diff mode.

Comment: and `tool = nvimdiff` in `[diff]` section of your .gitconfig if you use Git!

Answer (score 7):

I noticed a question about this was posted on redit: https://www.reddit.com/r/neovim/comments/6rvsa2/nvimdiff/

The dialog there confirms that there is no corresponding nvimdiff that is shipped. The solution suggested there is to add an alias in your bashrc file:

```bash
alias vimdiff='nvim -d'
```

I'll do this.

Comment: Ever got this to work? neither this suggestion nor putting `tool = nvim -d` in gitconfig seem to work.

Comment: @oarfish: This question pertains to using nvimdiff on the shell, not configuring git to use neovim. Per the accepted answer, I got vimdiff to work by aliasing it to `nvim -d`. That said, as far as git and `nvim -d`  is concerned, this may be helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61299449/629530

Comment: Aliasing doesn't seem to make sense, since git wouldn't have access to the shell alias by the time it tries to launch nvim. I got it to work using the solution in my own answer though.

Answer (score 1):

Git supports NeoVim natively since v2.29.0 from 2020.

- docs: [Documentation/mergetools/vimdiff.txt](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/mergetools/vimdiff.txt)
- commit: https://github.com/git/git/commit/11868978c7c80d3c29071b29e7964e3d62523819

You can try it out temporarily using e.g.

```
git -c 'diff.tool=nvimdiff' difftool
```

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using the following git config and it works well for me:

```
[diff]
    tool = nvimdiff
[difftool]
    prompt = false
[difftool "nvimdiff"]
    cmd = "nvim -d \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\""
[merge]
    tool = nvimdiff
[mergetool]
    prompt = true
[mergetool "nvimdiff"]
    cmd = "nvim -d \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$MERGED\" -c 'wincmd w' -c 'wincmd J'"
```